# Missing MethodInfo for overloaded function with different return type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a class defined as follows

```
interface ITest   
{  
   List<T> Find<T>(int i);   
}

class Test: ITest  
{  
    public T List<T> Find<T>(int i) { return default(T); }  
    List<T> ITest.Find<T>(int i) { return null; }  
}
```

When I use typeof(Test).GetMethods() (both with and without appropriate BindingFlags) I do not get the MethodInfo for ITest.Find function. What is the best way of getting the MethodInfo for the missing method?

Thanks

Comment: This doesn't compile. `public T List<T> Find(int i) { return default(T); }`

Comment: There was a typeo. the code should read public T List<T> Find<T>(int i)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean the following signature for the first `Find` method:

```
public T Find<T>(int i) { return default(T); }
```

(Your existing declaration doesn't compile; it has *two* return-types)

I think your issue is that by default, `GetMethods` doesn't return explicitly-implemented interface methods, which are private. However, it should work fine with these `BindingFlags`:

```
BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance
```

If you want *only* the two `Find` methods (and none of the inherited ones), throw in a `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly` as well.

**E.g.**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var flags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public |
                BindingFlags.Instance  | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly;

    foreach(var method in typeof(Test).GetMethods(flags))
         Console.WriteLine(method);
}
```

**Output**:

```
T Find[T](Int32)
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T] Program.ITest.Find[T](Int32)
```

Comment: Thanks. I am gonna try that. Why is ITest.Find private? IF i add public to the method I get compiler error. And how do I make ITest.Find public?

Comment: It's private because it is an *explicitly* implemented interface method. You have no choice but to do it this way as long as the other `Find` method has that signature, because otherwise, there's  ambiguity between the 2 methods (overloaded methods cannot vary *only* by return-type). Finally, it's not legal to attach access modifiers to explicitly implemented interface methods.

Answer (score 1):

Your explicitly implemented ITest.Find method is private.  You'll need to use BindingFlags in your GetMethods call:

```
        var methods = typeof(Test).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public |
                         BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

Comment: The code doesn't compile if I add public to the ITest.Find function. How do i make ITest.Find public?

Comment: Explicitly implemented interface method are not supposed to be public.  Check your favorite C# language book.  This is why I recommended you use BindingFlags.NonPublic.

Comment: The type is not generic, so `typeof(Test<>)` isn't correct. Only the methods are generic.

Comment: @Ani - the question originally had code that could not compile.  I had to guess.  Yes, in its current state, drop the <>.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Type.GetInterface`, make sure the return value is not null, and then use reflection on the it to get the type. For example:

```
var @class = typeof(Test);      
var methods = @class.GetMethods();      
PrintMethods("Test", methods);      

methods = @class.GetInterface("ITest", true).GetMethods();
PrintMethods("ITest", methods); 

static void PrintMethods(string typeName, params MethodInfo[] methods)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} methods:", typeName);
    foreach(var method in methods)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} returns {1}", method.Name, method.ReturnType);
    }   
}
```

Outputs (barring my separation space):

```
Test methods:
Find returns T
ToString returns System.String
Equals returns System.Boolean
GetHashCode returns System.Int32
GetType returns System.Type

ITest methods:
Find returns System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T]
```

EDIT:

Though Ani's answer seems to solve this for you without the need to resort what is suggested here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Type.GetInterfaces` to get all the interfaces implemented by a type, so the following should get all the methods:

```
Type t = typeof(Test);

IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methods = t.GetMethods()
    .Concat(t.GetInterfaces().SelectMany(i => i.GetMethods()));
```

Comment: I am gonna try that. Though without Linq. I am still stuck with .net 2.0. Anyway, can anyone clue me in what is going on? The function is part of the class Test so why the methodInfo is missing